# Wrap around in C for Ceasar's Code

Tags: c, arrays, file, word-wrap

Hey guy's last time I posted I was a bit sloppy. Hopefully this time it'll look a lot better . Thank you for your time if you decide to help me. I really need it. Anyways heres the question. I need to have wrap around for my Code and i heard you can do it with modulus but I am not sure i am doing it correctly because I do not get the right results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main () {
   char s[200]; //blank array//
   int mess;
   printf("Generations have wondered how the Ceasar Code works\n");
   printf("Please choose a number to mess up (encode) the current file\n");
   scanf("%d", &mess);
   mess = mess % 26;
   FILE *ptof = fopen("Rock.txt", "r");
   char a[200];//fill array with characters from file//
   int i=0;
   while( (a[i++]=fgetc(ptof)) != EOF && i < 89) { //get character from file//
   }
   a[i] = '\0'; /* null-terminate the string */
   i = 0;

   do{
      printf("%c",a[i++]);
   } while  (a[i] != '\0'); /* print until hit \0 */
   int j = 0;
   for (j = 0; j < 89; j++){
      s[j] = a[j] + mess;
   }
   printf("%s\n", s);

   fclose(ptof);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huh?  Even the "wrapping" tag you applied to your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: There's a good argument to be made that you should always close the output stream and report any errors, but there's not much point in closing the input.  If you aren't checking for errors, there's no point at all in closing the input.  (That's not strictly true, and closing files is a good idea, but if you don't check for errors you miss most of the benefits of doing so.)

Answer (score 3):

`s[j] = a[j] + mess` needs a modulo operation as well

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of room for improvement here.  Do you really want to map printable characters into (potentially) non-printable characters?  Or do you merely want to do a ceaser shift on letters in the alphabet?  Why the arbitrary limit of 90 characters of input?  Using scanf is never a good idea (in 20 some years writing code, I have never used it since I left school). Passing the shift on stdin rather than as an argument makes it hard to use your program as a filter.  For instance, it would be really nice if you could take a string and shift it by 4, then by 13, then by 9 and see that you get the original text back.  (eg `< file ceaser 4 | ceaser 13 | ceaser 9 | diff - file` should report no diffs).

Here's a few ideas:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *
xfopen( const char *path, const char *mode )
{
        FILE *ifp = fopen( path, mode );
        if( ifp == NULL ) {
                perror( path );
                exit( 1 );
        }
        return ifp;
}

int
main( int argc, char **argv )
{
        int mess = argc > 1 ? strtol( argv[1], NULL, 10 ) % 26 : 13;
        FILE *ptof = argc > 2 ? xfopen( argv[2], "r" ) : stdin;
        int c;

        while( ( c = fgetc( ptof )) != EOF ) {
                if( isupper( c ))
                        c = 'A' + ( c - 'A' + mess ) % 26;
                if( islower( c ))
                        c = 'a' + ( c - 'a' + mess ) % 26;
                putchar( c );
        }
        return 0;
}
```